# Downloads, Documents, Pictures Folders gone missing

Tags: 18.04, directory, filemanager

When I try to open Documents or Pictures folders I get the below error message.

> Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.

[image: Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.]

Following is the output of `cat .config/user-dirs.dirs`

```
> XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
> XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
> XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates" 
> XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
> XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/" 
> XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
> XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
> XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

read few suggestions on creating new folders and linking them through config but I don't understand whether those steps can restore the data. Please suggest if there is any way to bring back those folders and data.
EDIT: Output of `ls $HOME`

```
> Dropbox  'Screenshot from 2018-09-08 12-30-11.png'   soq.png    
> Videos  NewDocuments  'Screenshot from 2018-09-08 12-31-57.png'  
> Templates  rtlwifi_new    snap                                      
> Testproj
```

Comment: What is the out put of: `ls $HOME`?

Comment: Your current .config/user-dirs.dirs file suggests that you might have trashed all these folders: check your trash can.

Comment: Trash is empty.

Comment: As a test I did, I got the same error message deleting one of my special folders. In my opinion, these folders have either been deleted or they have been moved using the terminal or another not default file manager (with the default file manager, the `user-dir.dirs` file would be updated). You did not yet mention yet if `ls $HOME` still mentions the folders or not (see comment Ravexina).

Comment: @Ravexina, @vanadium updated the question with `ls $HOME` output.

Comment: This confirms that any special folder where "$HOME/" is given indeed has disappeared from your home folder. Your Video folder is still there. One or another way, you have moved or deleted these folders, which are there in a default installation. On a next reboot (logout/login may be sufficient), these entries will probably have disappeared from your left panel in the file manager, or, if they do not disappear, just move you to your home folder.